# Debugging ASP.NET MVC3 custom membership provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, membership-provider

I'm trying to test my asp.net mvc3 custom membership provider. I can't seem to be able to step into any of the code - all I want to do for now is validate that the user is logged in.

What I've done so far is:

Implement the abstact MembershipProvider class:

```
public class SSDSMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
        public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
        {
            return true;
        }
```

Modify the web.config to use my new provider:

```
  <membership defaultProvider="SSDSMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SSDSMembershipProvider" type="MvcApplication6.Infrastructure.SSDSMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Added the Authorize attribute to the about HomeController:

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Does the authorize attribute result in the ValidateUser method being called? If I put a breakpoint on ValidateUser it doesn't step in there and the browser goes straight to the logon page. Have I taken the right approach here?

Comment: `Authorize` just redirects the user to login page, validate user shall be called once the user puts in his/her credentials and submit the login form.

Comment: do you set your <authentication mode="">..., in <system.web> ?

Comment: @Furqan ah thanks at least I now know the CustomMembership provider is correctly configured - it still doesn't call ValidateUser once I've logged on though. I'm not going to use forms authentication - I actually need to use the username and password that is passed through as part of the http request from our app that handles the user login.

Comment: @tschmit007 Authentication mode was set to forms - I've realised that I need to change this because I need to use the username and password that is passed through as part of the request from our login app

Comment: @Furqan Change your comment to an answer if you want me to accept for reputation

Comment: @woggles, kindly accept the answer I entered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Authorize` just redirects the user to login page, validate user shall be called once the user puts in his/her credentials and submit the login form.

Answer (score 2):

did you change the code in your AccountController?

you have to change the code in the Method "LogOn" from Mebership.ValidateUser to a new instance of your SSDSMembershipProvider-Class and then call dthe ValidateUser method.

Comment: nope I hadn't changed the controller - I realise now that ValidateUser is called on logon, followed by a call to FromsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie. I thought that ValidateUser was called everytime the [Authorize] attribute appears.

Comment: http://www.brianlegg.com/post/2011/05/09/Implementing-your-own-RoleProvider-and-MembershipProvider-in-MVC-3.aspx this will help you! :)